# "Add this page to bookmark" within a frame

Tags: url, addition, frame, bookmarks

The title says it all I guess, how do I code a button to add a **frame**'s url to user's bookmarks??? Because "html bookmarks" are a thing and "html 'bookmark this page" link" is another, I googled for hours for this without any success...
Thanks in advance... I can provide the code while I do not see how it would clarify anything : just a page with frames and the button having to be nested into a frame that's all... Oh and I know, frames are supposedly deprecated, while my host still handles them for your information, so don't get smart on it...

Comment: Tried what's here : http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/navigation/bookmark.html but I get a JavaScript error saying "TypeError: window.external.AddFavorite is not a function". And i saw other examples with that same function...

Comment: This page here has a button that works (In Firefox at least) : https://www.thewebflash.com/how-to-add-a-cross-browser-add-to-favorites-bookmark-button-to-your-website/ but when I copy the code snipets in my frame it doesn't work. The problem is I cannot find within the code what points towards a specific url or window (the css part seems to be missing something...)

Comment: OK I solved it : the page linked in previous comment has working code, just don't forget to add the "rel='sidebar'" part to your <a> tag, as mentioned above the snipets... :D